# Monad evaluator with bind operator, not able to get what the syntax is about

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following:

```
module type MONAD_SIG =
  sig
    type 'a t
    val return : 'a -> 'a t
    val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
    val (>>=) : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
  end

module IdMonad : MONAD_SIG = 
  struct
    type 'a t = Id of 'a
    let return v = Id v
    let bind (Id v) f = f v
    let (>>=) = bind (* always the case *)
  end
    
type term = Const of int | Div of term * term

let e1 = Div (Div (Const 1972, Const 2), Const 23)

let e2 = Div (Const 1, Const 0)

module EvalIdMonad = struct
  include IdMonad

  let divM a b = return (a / b) (* will be different for each monad; type ?? *)

  let evalM t = (* will be the same across all monads; type ?? *)
    let rec evalMrec t = 
      match t with
    | Const c -> return c
    | Div(a,b) -> evalMrec a >>= fun n -> evalMrec b >>= fun d -> divM n d
  in evalMrec t
end

let _ = EvalIdMonad.evalM e1
```

This: `evalMrec a >>= fun n -> evalMrec b >>= fun d -> divM n d`
I have trouble understanding what it means or how it evaluates given that there is no parenthesis at least to illustrate.

What I get is that, first let's assume we reach the recursive basis and we have this:
`return c >>= fun n -> return c' >>= fun d -> divM n d`, how this will work? My guess is that we go innermost first, so, `return c' >>= fun d -> divM n d` evaluates first, and we get `divM n c'` and then `return c >>= fun n -> divM n c'` will return `divM c c'`, is that correct?

Also, can you illustrate how monad is helping here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the monad that you are using is the identity monad, it is not helping in any way, it is just a layer of syntactic boilerplate. In particular, `>>=` is just a version of `|>` (left-to-right) function evaluation that destructure the `Id _` constructor on this left side

```ml
evalMrec a >>= fun n -> evalMrec b >>= fun d -> divM n d
```

reads

```ml
evalMrec a |> (fun (Id n) ->
  evalMrec b |> (fun (Id d) ->
    divM n d
  )
)
```

which can be rewritten using let as

```
let Id n = evalMRec a in
let Id d = evalMRec b in
divM n d
```

Presumably, this is just an intermediary step in your textbook/homework before moving to more interesting examples. But you should not spend too much time trying to find deep meaning, at this point there are none.

Similarly

```ml
return c >>= fun n -> return c' >>= fun d -> divM n d
```

reads

```ml
(return c) >>= (fun n -> return c' >>= fun d -> divM n d)
```

and like any operators both sides of the operators are evaluated before the operator is applied to the results.

Comment: When you say "read" you mean that's correct syntax? This is correct Ocaml syntax: `let Id n = evalMRec a in
let Id d = evalMRec b in
divM n d` ? How can `Id n` be a value in `divM n d`?

Comment: So, for the operator evaluation sides, what I did was right in terms of going innermost?

Comment: `evalMRec a` is returning `Id <some int>`. Using the pattern `Id n` in the let binding is binding the name `n` to the actual `int` value.

Comment: Right, I got the big picture now.